# How to add the Spanish Accent in a SQL Data Base?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to modify the text of a Database in SQL that is linked to the generation of PDFs and Word Documents. To do this, I have used the UPDATE command to modify it. However, after the execution, it returns all the accents with a question mark after the vowel and it does not show it correctly. Could you help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance

the resulted text is like this: *un nu?mero de acciones de la accio?n subyacente con ma's subida en la u?ltima de?cada*

Mike

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: And the actual `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (These two may behave a bit different.)

Comment: Make sure you're using utf8mb4 as opposed to the incorrectly specified utf8

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, please verify that you use the right collation for your database (I guees it should be _Modern_Spanish_CI_AS_). Check this link for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the information first of all. I'm using UTF8 encoding and the text remains the same. I'm going to try to figure it our if we are using the right collation for the data base. if you any useful information regarding this matter, dont hesitate to comment please. Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft SQL Server**

To INSERT/UPDATE such value You should inform SQL that's an unicode string adding `N` in front of it, like so:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.myTable SET col = N'Strange string - начала'
```

To store accented letters using `varchar` type - use also a correct **collation** ([collation-and-unicode-support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15)).

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable 
ALTER COLUMN [message] varchar(800) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI;
```

I've had a similar problem with cyrylic letters (russian and ukrainian) for **multi-language** application.

For me the solution was to change data type from `varchar` to `nvarchar` in every table, procedure and function where it was needed.

More about [nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Tip**: Since I'm using JSON's I hope to upgrade to SQL Server 2019, where Microsoft implemented UTF-8 colation for `varchar` type.

Comment: The column could remain varchar but you should choose an appropriate collation, with Cyrillic in its name.

Comment: Thank You, You're right, but it's a multi-language application, so I can't use just one collation. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the information. Unfortunately,  it almost worked. I have used the N where you said and the texts shows like this: no devolverÃ¡ en efectivo, sino que entregarÃ¡, could you help me with this issue please?

Comment: Please confirm that You're using Microsoft SQL Server and not MySQL.

Comment: Hi Jan. thanks for your answer. I use Microsoft SQL Server. Regards Mike

Comment: @Mike, please supply the original accented text or the whole update query in Your main post, so I could try it myself.